# Handling Photos In Django Application

Tags: django, facebook, image, image-processing, instagram

I just finished developing a networking site for schools in my country. So far they can interact but completely in a textual way. No photos yet.

I want to start involving ability to share(uploading) images in the same way the can share text. I tried reading about how Instagram and Facebook handles photos but couldn't get answers to my questions:

### 1. What are the resources available for me to use when it comes to managing size, quality and maintaining aspect ratio?

### 2. Should I create separate image folder for each user or just a single folder for all even if we expect millions of photos?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the users uploading photos? In django you can use PIL library. if cost is affordable you can use amazon s3 to save the images.

Comment: Yes, users will be uploading photos.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL;  http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/. If you choose s3  http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/1.7.8/pythondoc-PIL.Image.html

Comment: http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/